# JSONArray from android to Array php

Tags: php, android, json

I am sending through some values from android/java to a server.

First I create a JSONArray object:

```
JSONArray JSONsamples = new JSONArray();
```

then I populate the JSONArray the following way:

```
 for(.....)
                {
                    if(...)
                    {
                      JSONsamples.put(storedArraylist.get(i));
                    }
                }
```

Then I send the value through post :

```
userParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("samples", JSONsamples.toString()));
.
.
Http_Client.executeHttpPost(getApplicationContext(), POST_url, userParameters);
.
```

Then on the server I try to store those values into a php array, but it does not work:

```
 $samplesarray = $_POST["samples"];
 $samplesarray = json_decode($samplesarray,true);
```

Before decoding, If I echo $samplesarray , I only get the first value encapsulated in these \"value\" , after json_decode , when I echo $samplesarray I get a parameter expected but null found error.

Please help.

Comment: echo $samplesarray to see exactly what do you get and let us know

Comment: I only get the first value, like this \"blood\" and after I get this []

Comment: you know, that "samplesDESCRIPTION" != "samples" right?

Comment: @fix , just a typo in my post, fixed it thx.

Comment: @Janpan is that entire output of echo? (\"blood\" I mean please paste entire out put of `echo $samplesarray` before json_decode)

Comment: try the php page in firebug and see what is the response content being returned , if it is same as \blood\ , you need to check your android code

Comment: That is the entire output, just the first value, which is \"blood\". I'll run it again to make sure, gimme a minute.

Comment: it seems that `\"blood\"` is what `JSONsamples.toString()` returns. Or maybe it is `"blood"` if you have enabled magic_quotes. What is the expected return value of `JSONsamples.toString()`?

Comment: @imsiso , this is the output :

[before decode][[\"blood\"]][after decode][]

Comment: @steven , the expected value is something in the lines of "value","value2","value3","value4" , not just []

Comment: what is the output of JSONSamples.toString() in your ANdroid code

Comment: The `\"blood\"` is not a valid JSON thats the problem I think.

Comment: @Satya , the output is ["blood"] , however I suppose when you do JSONSamples.toString() it only prints the first element of the array ?

Comment: ignore the resulting `[]`! it happens because you cannot `json_decode` a string like `\"blood\"`. `JSONsamples.toString()` should return something like this: `["value1","value2","value3"]` or `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}` and you need to disable magic_quotes!

Comment: thx @steven , I disabled magicquotes (should have done that from the start) , however, now my output is as follows: [before decode][["blood"]][after decode][Array]

Comment: ok, you are right now! so do `echo $samplesarray[0]` after decoding and you will see `blood`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic Quotes should be turned off because it adds a `\` before your `"` values.
This breakes the json data in your case.

Please read more about why you should not use magicquotes here:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php

Answer (score 0):

The solution is removing magic quotes, or at least checking if its on or not and working from there. @steven reminded me of this, thank you.

So on the server side, I do the following check to ensure correct json and it works :

```
$samplesarray = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($_REQUEST['samples']) : $_REQUEST['samples'];
```